# apache proxypass https to http not working

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, proxy, http, https

I have the following configuration:

1. An apache with SSL configured and this server is accessible via the internet.
2. A second apache in the local network of the other apache but this one don't have SSL enabled.
3. Every http Request on the first apache is redirected to https for security reasons.
4. Also the first apache has configured to proxypass to the second apache.

first apache conf:

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>   ServerName someapp.test.de
>
>   Redirect permanent / https://someapp.test.de
> </VirtualHost>
>
> <VirtualHost *:443>
>   ServerName someapp.test.de
>   ProxyRequests off
>   ProxyPass / http://192.168.0.3
>   ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.0.3
>   SSLEngine On
>   SSLCertificateFile /path/to/certificate
>   SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/key
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

second apache conf:

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>   DocumentRoot /var/www/someapp
>
>   ...
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

The Problem now is that when I try to access someapp.test.de then I got an internal server error on the second apache with the following message:

> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.

Did I miss something or did I just thinking the wrong way?

Edit:
I found the problem..I forgot to enable the proxy_http module. I only enabled the proxy module but not the proxy_http module which causes the problem. Now everything works fine!

Comment: Try to add :80 and RedirectMatch clause... x=t in example : 
ProxyPass / hxxp://192.168.0.3:80
  ProxyPassReverse / hxxp://192.168.0.3:80
  RedirectMatch ^/$ hxxps://someapp.test.de

Comment: Added this to my config but still getting the same error.

Comment: They both work proper by themselves.. i mean if you say 192.168.0.3 in browser you see the index from the first (HTTPS) right? - http://www.giuseppeurso.eu/en/redirect-from-http-to-https-and-viceversa-with-apache-proxypass/

Comment: Now everything works. See the edit in my post.